# UITextfield rotation with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation not calculating correctly

Tags: uitextfield, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to rotate a UITextfield using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to match the angle of a triangle drawn on the screen.
As you can see on the picture, the rotation angle is not correct.

to calculate the angle i an using :-

```
viewwidth = topView2.bounds.size.width/2;
viewheight = topView2.bounds.size.height;
angle = atan(viewheight/viewwidth);
```

to rotate the textfield I'm using :-

```
 [self->textField7 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-self->angle)];
```

the result is not satisfactory.
you can see in the screenshot, the textfield is not rotated at the same angle as the drawn line.
values in the centre of the screenshot show the view height , width and angle in radians from the above code.

can somebody please advise what I'm doing wrong.

thanks
[image: view screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a line along the baseline of the 9,579,739,797 it extends right up to the middle of 4:40 PM.  It looks to me like you are using the wrong height:

```
viewheight = topView2.bounds.size.height;
```

It looks like you are either not accounting for the stuff at the top of the screen (green line and/or nav bar) or the stuff at the bottom of the screen (indigo line and/or tab bar)

Comment: I've done some more fishing and found that the Rect size being used by drawrect for rendering the triangle is 375 wide and 415 high. this is why the angle is miscalculated , but i don't understand why the drawrect is getting different sizes than the view. the view sizes are on the picture and represent the white area on the picture can you explain how to pass the correct view sizes to drawrect

Comment: Have you used the "Debug View Hierarchy" button on XCode to make sure the view is what you think it is, and its not covered up a little by something else?